# Can many creatures attune to an item at once?

Tags: dnd-5e, magic-items, attunement

Can multiple creatures attune to the same magic item at a time? Ignore issues with attuning to a weapon - assume this is an item that can be attuned to with meditation.

Anyway, if one creature is taking a short rest to attune to an item, and another creature begins one to attune to the same item, what happens? Does anything odd happen when the first one finishes?

Comment: Are you the DM or a player?

Comment: @ThomasMarkov DMing right now, though it hasn't come up. I'm considering actually having a villain with a bunch of noodle bugs, money, and nothing else, and trying to figure out what he can do.
Thanks for that edit! Didn't realize that was a tag.

Comment: So basically you're asking whether your homebrew creatures can use a homebrew magic item using an _extremely_ loose reading of the attunement rules in a way that _probably_ wasn't intended to achieve a result that is _very_ obviously game breaking?

Comment: @Cubic I see how it looks that way. I should probably delete the question and split this into two parts: "Can multiple creatures attune to an item at the same time, and will one be interrupted by the other finishing?" and "Can a once-per-day effect be used by multiple people, attuning and using it?"

Comment: I think the thing you should take from Cubics comment is 'very obviously game breaking' and I would suggest focusing your planning around standard interactions. It worries me that you have written this question in a manner that suggests you intend to actually do this

Comment: @SeriousBri I have absolutely no intent to do this. I want to know whether magic items can be attuned to by several people at once. I also want to know whether once-per-rest items can be used by several people, one attuning after the other. I was planning to reask this as two questions, which I think is much better, but currently I'm unsure since it would mean deleting these answers.

Comment: @SeriousBri To clarify, I'm not thinking of using Noodle Bugs for this. I was thinking about Noodle Bugs, and wondered if this were possible. I think I tried to use an example that was so concrete that people started worrying about the example - it was supposed to be a reductio ad absurdum, not something I would do. Do you think I should edit the question so it asks about a more general case, and remove the example?

Comment: @Phoenices If you want to edit this question to the more simple "can two creature be in the process of attuning to an item at the same time", I'm okay with deleting my answer (since it doesn;t actually address that question at all), and the remaining answer seems to actually approach that question.

Comment: @Phoenices Removing the specific scenario of the noodle bugs and the homebrew item might make this simpler, but I think you should **restore** the clarification of individual creatures starting at specific times. Maybe not every round, but every minute or every 10 minutes, so that every minute (or 10) after the short rest, one creature would get "pushed out" by the next creature who gets attuned.

Comment: @Mołot The answer that was invalidated was mine, and I suggested the change and deleted my answer.

Comment: @ThomasMarkov it is also a significant part of the other answer.

Comment: I agree with Molot. We try not to make questions "moving targets" here. I know that it was advised to make the question more simple, but there is another existing answer that heavily relies on the previous version of the question. I'd personally recommend rolling back the previous edit.

Comment: Oh, one small suggestion too: the title of your question ("Can many creatures attune to an item at once?") made me think you were asking if many creatures could *be* attuned to an item simultaneously. You might want to change the wording of the question to make it clear that you're asking if creatures can be in the process of attuning to an item simultaneously (and what, if anything, happens if one finishes attuning before the others). Honestly, this is part of why I thought you should roll back your previous edit: it was clearer what you were asking before.

Answer (score 5):

## Probably not by RAI. Moreover, there are no situations where allowing this would be useful for official DMG magic items.

At the end of your question, you say:

> note that I'm not asking if the item is balanced, merely if this works.

This isn't so much about whether the item is imbalanced, as how it interacts with your question. The question is only relevant because the item, as designed, breaks the mold of other magic items (at least those found in the DMG).

Some important parts of the DMG rules regarding attunement:

> Attuning to an item requires a creature to spend a Short Rest focused on only that item while being in physical contact with it (this can’t be the same short rest used to learn the item’s properties). This focus can take the form of weapon practice (for a weapon), meditation (for a wondrous item), or some other appropriate activity. […]
>
> An item can be attuned to only one creature at a time […].

Since an item can be attuned to only one creature at a time, and attuning requires a short rest, under what circumstances would two creatures attempt to attune to the same magic item? If they were rivals, they wouldn't do so voluntarily. One would have to defeat the other or run away with the item someplace where they could rest without interruption. If they voluntarily agreed to spend overlapping short rests attuning, creature A would lose attunement as soon as creature B's short rest completed. If they are allies, why would they do this?

The answer is that there are no items in the DMG where this would be beneficial to do so. No DMG magic items recharge on a short rest the way your homebrew item does.

- Most limited use items have charges. These charges are usually restored at a particular time of day, like "at dawn", regardless of whether the item requires attunement or whether the attuned item owner rests.
- A small number of magic items regain a use after a particular period of time, such as a *frost brand*, which can "extinguish all non-magical flames within 30 feet of you […] no more than once per hour."
- Only one item that I have found so far regains uses after a rest, *boots of speed*: "When the boots' property has been used for a total of 10 minutes, the magic ceases to function until you finish a long rest."

**It is almost definitely the case that allowing overlapping attuning periods is not Rules As Intended. It was not specifically addressed because there would never be a benefit to doing so.** The vast majority of items recharge at a set time of day or after a specific period that is unrelated to character rests. The *boots of speed* recharges after a long rest. If you disagreed with my interpretation of RAI, there is still no way that I can see characters wanting to spend overlapping short rests attuning to *boots of speed* that would increase its usefulness.

Basically, it seems like you want a way for your noodle bugs to shoot fireballs without increasing their CR by actually giving them the power to shoot fireballs. It also seems like you are trying to shoehorn the scenario that you have in mind into part of the ruleset (attunement) that is not designed to handle it. Why would a wizard (or other magic item fabricator) ever create a large, slow-moving object that requires attunement? In game terms, attunement exists for game balance. But in world, fabricators would probably make some items require attunement (like a *wand of fireballs*) in order to make it harder for the item to be turned on them by an enemy. A catapult would probably achieve the same thing by being behind walls, and not easily repositioned to target you even if the enemy does breach the walls. So why are you going through this rigmarole with attunement?

I can think of several ways for you to change this item so that it can be useful in this scenario without requiring attunement:

- Require a command word which only the noodle bugs know.
- Have the item triggered by a button that magically can only be pressed by a noodle bug.
- Have a fixed number of charges that the item never regains.
- Have the noodle bug **become the fireball**, so the item can never be used without an army of insane noodle bugs.

There are many other solutions which would involve a minor redesign of the item, and would not require altering or arguing over the magic item attunement rules.

Comment: Rod of the Pact Keeper? A warlock cult, if this works, could spend an hour and a minute to all regain a warlock spell slot. Nevermind, I'm a fool - they could use that short rest to all regain all spell slots, because warlocks.

Comment: @Phoenices I will add Rod of the Pact Keeper, although note that it works once per long rest, not once per short rest. Wow, I just realized that some additional text I added seems to have been lost when I tried to post it. I'm going to update this now.

Comment: I think I'm changing the question, splitting it into two parts and removing the example, because my example was confusing. This question will be "can multiple people attune to an item at once" and I'll also ask "can I use a once-per-long-rest item like Hat of Wizardry multiple times with this?" Sorry that this invalidates your answer for this question.